# How can I use aws-cw-agent on an EC2 hosted in private subnet ( without NAT gateway)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to upload logs of applications hosted in my private AMZ EC2 machine to the log group ( Cloudwatch ) by using the AWS Cloudwatch agent, However, I am stuck with how to do this task without using NAT Gateway or jump/ NAT Instance.
TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [VPC interface endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html) to privately connect to cloudwatch logs without any internet access. Amazon CloudWatch Logs is [supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/aws-services-privatelink-support.html) endpoint.

Comment: I cannot install aws-cloudwatch agent on a private subnet since it requires internet connectivity to download libraries/utilities.
and without this agent I won't be able to post application error logs.

Comment: @Mirza Create custom AMI with the agent pre-installed.

Comment: I have found a standalone version of aws-CW-agent. Thank you so much.

link: ( go to the end of page)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html